# Send messages manually with Microsoft bot framework

Tags: azure, botframework

I have mbf and luis app which gives automatic reply. In some cases agent can reply with bot-service rest-api, it is working fine skype but not sms or web channel.

ref  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: What errors are your getting when connecting to the sms and web channel?

Answer (score -1):

For SMS you need to configure twilio and for web channel you need to use web chat contri